# Using broadcast variables in apache spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, lambda, apache-spark-sql

I am getting an error while using broadcast variable inside a  CoGroupFunction. The error disappears if `appProvider.value()` is commented. Have you any idea how to solve this issue ? is the error related to the variable definition or initialization ?

```
public class UsageJobDS implements Serializable{
  private static final Logger log = org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger("myLogger");

  Broadcast<Provider> appProvider;

  void init(){
    // init broadcast variable
    ....
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    UsageJobDS ujb = new UsageJobDS();
    ujb.init();
    ujb.run();
  }

  void run(){
    KeyValueGroupedDataset<Long, Row> charges = usageCharges.groupByKey(x -> x.getLong(x.fieldIndex("si__subscription_id")), Encoders.LONG());

    Dataset<ProcessEdr> cogg = edrs.cogroup(charges, rateEDRs, Encoders.bean(ProcessEdr.class));

    log.warn("Count cogg " + cogg.count());
  }

  CoGroupFunction<Long, EDR2, Row, ProcessEdr> rateEDRs = (subscription_id, edrsIter, chargesIter) -> {
        Logger log = org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger("myLogger");
        log.warn("inside rateEDRs function");

        while (edrsIter.hasNext()) {
            appProvider.value(); // HERE
        }
        return results.iterator();
    };

}
```

and I am getting this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.opencell.spark.jobs.UsageJobDS.rateEDRs of type org.apache.spark.api.java.function.CoGroupFunction in instance of org.opencell.spark.jobs.UsageJobDS
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2233)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1405)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2288)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it works if the cogroup function definition is changed to the below code. However, the error cause still unknown.

```
        Dataset<ProcessEdr> cogg = edrs.cogroup(charges, (subscription_id, edrsIter, chargesIter) -> {
            ArrayList<ProcessEdr> results = new ArrayList<>();

            System.out.println("App Provider name" + appProvider.value().getIssuer_name());

            return results.iterator();
        }, Encoders.bean(ProcessEdr.class));
```